# MVC Razor - Special characters not rendering in page meta tags

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, meta-tags

I'm trying to add page meta tags in my MVC 4 application.
Here is my Layout's header:

```
<title>@Html.Raw(Model.CurrentPageMetaTags.Title)</title>
<meta name="description" content="@Html.Raw(Model.CurrentPageMetaTags.Description)" />
<meta name="keywords" content="@Html.Raw(Model.CurrentPageMetaTags.Keywords)" />
```

Meta tags being populated from model as:

```
Title = "Current page's title";
Description = "Current page's description";
Keywords = "Current page's keywords";
```

But when it comes to the browser it shows meta tags as followings:

```
<title>Current page's title</title>
<meta name="description" content="Current page&#39;s description" />
<meta name="keywords" content="Current page&#39;s keywords" />
```

**There is no issue with the title but special characters not rendering for description and keywords!**

Comment: What's the problem? What do you mean by "not rendering", meta tags don't get rendered.

Comment: Yes @CodeCaster. apostrophe didn't got rendered in meta description & keywords!

Comment: Again, what do you mean by that? Meta tags don't get rendered. What do you think "render" means, what output do you expect?

Comment: @CodeCaster Apostrophe shows up as #39;s in Meta description and keywords content! Any solution to this problem?

Comment: That's not a problem. I'm also fairly sure that it's simply your browser showing you that. Are you looking at the _source_ or the _DOM_?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line to the httpRuntime line inside the Web.config file.

encoderType="System.Web.Security.AntiXss.AntiXssEncoder"

```
<httpRuntime encoderType="System.Web.Security.AntiXss.AntiXssEncoder" requestValidationMode="2.0" enableVersionHeader="false" targetFramework="4.7.2" maxRequestLength="51200" fcnMode="Single" />
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this might help you:

```
@Html.Raw(WebUtility.HtmlDecode(Model.CurrentPageMetaTags.Title))
```

Cheers

Comment: Please explain why you think it is answer for OP's problem.  If it's suggestion you want OP to try, you may well suggest as a comment

Comment: @shwnz Thanks for your answer, Problem was solved. There was no problem with the code, It was showing in the source in that way!